# Подключение платежной системы epay

Tags: php

Понадобилось мне подключить платежную систему *epay* на сайт - сайт к слову рукописный.

гуглил в интернетах, но там либо плагины для популярных КМС, либо сторонние люди предлагают за деньги подключить. Хотелось бы попросить - может кто сталкивался с моей проблемой и подскажет где найти урок или пример скрипта?

Comment: Как вы интересно искали [Epay payment API](http://tech.epay.dk/en/payment-web-service)

Comment: я слежу за вопросом) просто разбераю документацию скоро добьюсь успеха - опишу полученное мной решение и похвалю того чей ответ наиболее мне помог)

Comment: Да коечно) сейчас я отладил стадию платежа - осталось теперь наладить ответ от банка при успешном платеже - что бы он отправлял на сайт ХМЛ запрос - который сайт анализирует и при положительном ответе отправляет заказ в обработку со статусом оплчаен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем было примерно так попытаюсь объяснить вот тут лежит нужная информация на русском(!) https://testpay.kkb.kz/doc/htm/ а именно стоит скачать пункт 3 "Примеры подключения, тестовые сертификаты и тестовые карты:" теперь объясню как это работает - подключал я по php (папка в архиве "paysystem_PHP" там мануал есть еще) в общем там все ясно вот такой скрипт отправляет данные в банк:

```
<?php
require_once("../paysys/kkb.utils.php");
$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$path1 = '../paysys/config.txt';    // Путь к файлу настроек config.dat
$order_id = 1;              // Порядковый номер заказа - преобразуется в формат "000001"
 $currency_id = "398";          // Шифр валюты  - 840-USD, 398-Tenge
 $amount = 10;              // Сумма платежа
 $content = process_request($order_id,$currency_id,$amount,$path1); // Возвращает подписанный и base64 кодированный XML документ для отправки в банк
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pay</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
 </head>
 <body>
 <form name="SendOrder" method="post" action="https://epay.kkb.kz/jsp/process/logon.jsp">
  <input type="hidden" name="Signed_Order_B64" value="<?php echo $content;?>">
   E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" size=50 maxlength=50  value="test@test.kz">
   <p>
   <input type="hidden" name="Language" value="eng"> <!-- язык формы оплаты rus/eng -->
   <input type="hidden" name="BackLink" value="ссылка на страницу вашего сайта - 'оплата прошла успешно'">
    <input type="hidden" name="PostLink" value="очень важная ссылка см.ниже">
```

Со счетом согласен (-а)

форму можете както интегрировать по своему - я лично ее полностью скрытой сделал и запустил гет элемент бай i. подключенные файлы - тоже важны - в конфиге содержатся пути к ключам а во втором класс по фрмировке запросса 
к слову о ключах их вам выдадут целый набор в банке - все они вам не нужны так как они каждый для своего метода - т.е. один для php другой там для C# и тд. там же в мануале есть и описание какой для какого но я на всякий случай их все закинул в папку paysys

далее - банк принимает ваш запрос юзверь вводит там платежные данные и как мы видим у нас в форме по мимо остального 3 важные ссылки (!) BackLink - это вы создаете на своем сайте страницу на которую будет перенаправлять пользователя при успешной оплате FailureBackLink - страница при неудаче в процессе оплаты и самая важная PostLink - страница сайта в которую Epay отправляет xml реквест при удачной оплате! -  (пример ее есть в документации к слову называется postlink.php) в моей реализации на этой странице - при удачном реквесте 
1 - скрипт лезет в базу данных помечая там заказ как "ожидающий"
2 - вытаскивает из корзины то что заказал юзер (в этом плане идентифицировать пользователя провевшего оплату можно либо по уникальному номеру заказа который возвращается банком в переменной  $result['ORDER_ORDER_ID']; или по емэйлу $result['CUSTOMER_MAIL'];) 
3 - формирует 2 письма - на почту владельца сайта с данными заказа что бы он мог взять оплаченный заказ в обработку и самому пользователю если вам так хочется его известить что заказ принят в обработку 
выглядит се примерно так

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 include("../bd.php");

 include("../maga/sest.php");
 require_once("../paysys/kkb.utils.php");
 $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
 $path1 = '../paysys/config.txt';
 $result = 0;
 if(isset($_POST["response"])){$response = $_POST["response"];};
 $result = process_response(stripslashes($response),$path1);
 if (is_array($result)){
    if (in_array("ERROR",$result)){
    if ($result["ERROR_TYPE"]=="ERROR"){
        echo "System error:".$result["ERROR"];
    } elseif ($result["ERROR_TYPE"]=="system"){
        echo "Bank system error > Code: '".$result["ERROR_CODE"]."' Text: '".$result["ERROR_CHARDATA"]."' Time: '".$result["ERROR_TIME"]."' Order_ID: '".$result["RESPONSE_ORDER_ID"]."'";
    }elseif ($result["ERROR_TYPE"]=="auth"){
        echo "Bank system user autentication error > Code: '".$result["ERROR_CODE"]."' Text: '".$result["ERROR_CHARDATA"]."' Time: '".$result["ERROR_TIME"]."' Order_ID: '".$result["RESPONSE_ORDER_ID"]."'";
    };
};
  $emai = $result['CUSTOMER_MAIL'];//емэйл того кто оплатил
 $orderid = $result['ORDER_ORDER_ID'];//номер заказа


   /*вот тут вы и делаете свои махинации с базами данных с письмами 
  оплата то прошла и все хорошо    
  */
 }
```

что еще нужно знать - номер заказа должен быть не менее 6ти символов приведенный выше скрипт его и преобразует в такой формат. я сидел разбирался и настраивал эту системку дня два что бы все работала так как мне надо - надеюсь вам поможет этот пост разобраться гораздо быстрее - есть вопросы стучите время от времени я тут бываю)

З.Ы. - на include("../maga/sest.php"); вот эту штуку к слову вобще не смотрите - это специфичный файл к делу он ни как не относится это что то вроде конфигурации баз данных

Answer (score 0):

> Это самые простые способы интегрировать Epay, поскольку они требует
>   только минимум опыта программирования. Весь необходимый код
>   генерируется автоматически при подключении JavaScript.

[Варианты интеграции из технической документации epay в примерах](http://tech.epay.dk/en/payment-window-integration)

Пример интеграции через iframe из офф. документации:

```
<script charset="UTF-8" src="https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/integration/ewindow/paymentwindow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="payment-div"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    paymentwindow = new PaymentWindow({
        'merchantnumber': "ENTER YOUR MERCHANT NUMBER HERE",
        'amount': "10095",
        'currency': "DKK",
        'windowstate': "2"
    });
    paymentwindow.append('payment-div');
    paymentwindow.open();
</script>
```